# How to extract a path components from documents directory till my file name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

In my iPhone Application,

I want to extract a path components....

```
/Users/priyadarshanjoshi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/A2CD9285-62E9-4447-9945-5D8CE090FB3A/Documents/Wine_12.png
```

I want to extract

```
/Documents/Wine_12.png
```

I am writing this code...

**Is there any easier way to do the same?**

```
NSString *relativePathImage1=@"";
        BOOL append=NO;
        for(NSString *get in [imagePath pathComponents])
        {
            if([get isEqualToString:@"Documents"])
            {
                append=YES;
            }
            if(append==YES)
            {
            relativePathImage1=[relativePathImage1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:get];
            }
    }
        NSLog(@"relativePathImage1 %@",relativePathImage1);
```

Comment: Never let your personal information on SO... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you take help of below function? It would result into 2 strings in an array,before document and after document. Yu can then use the string after document and append document/ in the same and use it.

```
   [strPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"Document"]
```

Comment: Right!!! But If I would be more greedy can I get the Documents also...!!??? means I am getting two strings   /../../Documents and /Wine_15.png Thanks...

Comment: no and the reason is the key value before document differs each time..otherwise i was not having any problem.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *fullPath = // Get the path to your image
NSString *pathWithNoFileName = [fullPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *myPath = [[pathWithNoFileName lastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fullPath lastPathComponent]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `lastPathComponent` wilt give you `Wine_12.png`.

The method `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` will give you `/Users/priyadarshanjoshi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/A2CD9285-62E9-4447-9945-5D8CE090FB3A/Documents`.

And you can take the `lastPathComponent` of the second one... then combine.